# conditional redirect using react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use loaders, actions etc to redirect, [see here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/route)

But it simply does not work, I tried it like this

loader: async () => redirect(routes.homeMain),

As this was not working I tried to redirect inside a component in useEffect using [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) and [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect).

var navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(()=>navigate(homeRoute), []);

// doesn't work

if (condition) redirect(route);

relevant part (using redirect)

```js
{
    path: routes.adminRoot,
    loader: () => (notAuthenticated ? redirect("/") : null),
    element: (
      <div>
        <Navigationbar isAdmin={true} />
        <div className="mt-36 px-14 max-sm:px-6">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
```

router.jsx

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: routes.root,
    element: (
      <div>
        <Navigationbar isAdmin={false} />
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    ),
    children: [
      { path: routes.home, element: <Homepage /> },
      {
        path: routes.contact,
        element: <ContactMe />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.resume,
        element: <Resume />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.portfolio,
        element: <Portfolio />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.projectPage,
        element: <ProjectPage />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.blog,
        element: <Blogs />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.blogPage,
        element: <BlogPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/editor",
        element: <Editor />,
      },
    ],
  },

  // >>-------------------| ADMIN |-----------------<<
  {
    path: routes.adminRoot,
    // redirecting here
    loader: () => (notAuthenticated ? redirect("/") : null),
    element: (
      <div>
        <Navigationbar isAdmin={true} />
        <div className="mt-36 px-14">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    ),

    children: [
      {
        path: routes.dashboard,
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: routes.adminHomeRoot,
        children: [
          { path: routes.homeMain, element: <HomeMain /> },
          { path: routes.homeHero, element: <HomeHero /> },
          { path: routes.homePortfolio, element: <HomePortfolio /> },
          { path: routes.homeServices, element: <HomeServices /> },
          {
            path: routes.homeTestimonials,
            element: <HomeTestimonials />,
          },
          { path: routes.homeBlog, element: <HomeBlog /> },
          { path: routes.homeFAB, element: <HomeFAB /> },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: routes.adminPortfolioRoot,
        children: [
          {
            path: routes.portfolioMain,
            element: <EditPortfolio />,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: routes.adminResumeRoot,
        children: [
          {
            path: routes.resumeMain,
            element: <EditResume />,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: routes.adminBlogRoot,
        children: [
          {
            path: routes.blogMain,
            element: <EditBlog />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to redirect, let alone conditionally, anywhere in the code snippet you shared. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish or what any specific issue is. Can you [edit] to clarify what the issue is and what you need specific help with?

Comment: Please see now. Thank you. only authenticated person should access admin/dashboard pages and it should redirect if they are not loggedin/authenticated. Can i achieve this with loaders or actions ? If not how can i redirect ? I'm using createBrowserRouter, can i use navlink some how ? I used useEffect to redirect inside component But it doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a layout for private routes and check authentication in that layout component, if not authenticated or the condition evaluates to false return Navigate Component.

```
 {
    // layout route
    element: <PrivateLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/users",
        element: <div>Users</div>,
      },
      // ... all private routes
    ],
  }
```

PrivateLayout component body example

```
   if(condition)
     return <Navigate to="/login" />;
   
   return <Outlet />;
```